# PYTHON (Plotly) - Renaming axis ticks

Tags: python, plotly

I have a line graph which I have done with matplotlib from this dataframe called lineFGDF:

[image]

The code I used is:

```
fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
x = lineFDF[threeYr]
x.plot(kind='line', marker='',color='#0c1e3c')
plt.grid(color='#e5e0e0', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.8)
```

It produces this:

[image]

Which is great and I can see the Months on the X axis. However, I want to do it with Plotly so I can make it interactive.

So I found a way of doing it in Plotly, but the months have gone and have been replaced with numbers. How do I get the month labels back?

This is the code:

```
random_x = lineFDF[threeYr]
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    y = random_x,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = 'lines'
)
data = [trace0]
plotly.offline.iplot(data, filename='line-mode')
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify X in your trace0. Set X to be equal to the the months you would like to see.

```
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x = ['jan','feb','ma','ap','may','jun'],
    y = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    mode = 'lines',
    name = 'lines'
)
```

results in this graph.

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! :)